# Порядок действий в C++

Tags: c++, функции

Есть код:

```
SomeObject.DoA().DoB().DoC();
```

В каком порядке выполнятся функции DoA(), DoB(), DoC()?

Comment: а есть какие-то сомнения? Как можно тут чисто в теории поменять порядок вызова?

Comment: @pavel у меня нет сомнений - я просто не знаю. Никогда не задумывался на эту тему.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Более формально можно сказать и так. Оператор `.` имеет [левую ассоциативность](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).
Поэтому выражение выше можно рассматривать так:

```
((SomeObject.DoA()).DoB()).DoC();
```

тут вроде вопросов про порядок уже никаких не возникает.

Answer (score 5):

Просто по логике: к чему применяется `f()` в `a.f()`? К объекту `a`. К чему применяется `DoC()`? к результату `DoB()`. Как его получить, сначала вызвав `DoC()`? Никак. Значит, `DoB()` - предшествует `DoC()`. То же самое относится и к порядку `DoA()` и `DoB()`.